# How to make div underneath fixed div stack below?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, twitter-bootstrap

I'm using bootstrap and I have three rows, the second row is initially hidden and is displayed once the row before it scrolls past the nav-bar.

However the third row that follows the hidden second row is underneath the second  row when the second row appears. How can I make it so that the third row is displayed beneath the second row and not underneath? So when the second row appears the page looks like two regular rows in bootstrap.I want to make it so that the third row and the rest of the page can scroll underneath the second row. The scrolling works just that the third row always appears underneath and not below the the second row.

```
<div id="thumbnails1" class="row">
        <div class="col-xs-6 col-sm-6 col-lg-3 col-md-4">
            <div class="thumbnail">
                <img src="http://placehold.it/320x150" alt="">
                <div class="caption">
                    <p>See more snippets like this online item at <a target="_blank" href="http://www.bootsnipp.com">Bootsnipp - http://bootsnipp.com</a>.</p>
                </div>

            </div>
        </div>
      </div>

<div id="body-1" class="row">
            <div class="col-xs-6 col-sm-6 col-lg-3 col-md-4">
                <div class="thumbnail">
                    <img src="http://placehold.it/320x150" alt="">
                    <div class="caption">
                        <p>See more snippets like this online item at <a target="_blank" href="http://www.bootsnipp.com">Bootsnipp - http://bootsnipp.com</a>.</p>
                    </div>

                </div>
            </div>
          </div>
```

CSS:

```
.stuck {
  position: fixed;
  top: 0px;
  display: block;
  z-index: 11;
}

#thumbnails1 {
  display: none;
  background-color: black;
  clear: both;
}
```

javascript for scroll:

```
var mainbottom2 = $('#nav-bar-1').offset().top + $('#nav-bar-1').height();


                // on scroll,
                $(window).on('scroll',function(){      
                    stop = Math.round($(window).scrollTop());
                    stop += mainbottom2;
                    if (stop > mainbottom) {
                        $('#thumbnails1').addClass("stuck");
                        $('#thumbnails1').show();
                    } else {
                        $('#thumbnails1').removeClass("stuck");
                        $('#thumbnails1').hide();
                    }
```

Comment: Can you provide a fiddle or similar? Looks like you've left out some important code (e.g the actual `.stuck` element)

Comment: "third row is displayed beneath the second row and not underneath"   do you mean it is hidden?  I'm unclear as to what you mean with "beneath" vs "underneath".

Comment: By underneath I mean that second row is displayed on top of the third row. I would like it below in rows.

Comment: stuck is just a class I add to the hidden row when the first row passes the nav-bar

Comment: The second row is the row with the id = thumbnails1